# Dynamic titles/descriptions for iOS auto-renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I've read in other posts that this is not possible. However, somehow YouTube seems to be doing it - you can see in the screenshot that the subscription display name is "Marques Brownlee" which is the name of the channel / content creator.

I would like to programmatically create auto-renewable subscriptions on behalf of app users.

How is YouTube dynamically creating iOS subscription groups?

[image: YouTube channel membership]

Comment: Or, they have just created specific IAP subscriptions for each channel

Comment: I considered this but they would be capped at 10K subscriptions which is probably far less than the number of channels.

Comment: The other possibility is that they have worked with Apple to circumvent this restriction.  Once you have as many users as YouTube you probably can too :)